# Using a div within a wrapper to change another div with hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to hover over a div and change another when they are within a flex wrapper.

I want to hover over the `<li>` elements to expand other divs in the wrapper.

Specifically the `li` links in the navbar that respectively goes to the inner divs.

code pen example :
https://codepen.io/popados/pen/JjpyvqO

EDIT: The code pen shows an example that works if you hover the wrapper but not the div I want to (the home button).

Ideally, I would like to expand the about author box to 1024 x 768 while hovering one of the li element divs.

EDIT 2: Added a comment down below. Images added. Shows what the expected output should be. Changed HTML to remove  around a li element.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: green;
}

header {
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 1024px;
  height: 768px;
}

a:visited {
  color: green;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  flex-direction: column;
}

li {
  border: 2px solid red;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 25px;
}

.nav-bar {
  background-color: black;
  color: red;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
}

.nav-bar-text {
  height: 125px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}

.home {
  transition: all 2s ease-out;
}

.home:hover {
  background-color: rgb(71, 71, 71);
}

.wrapper:hover .about {
  background-color: rgb(71, 71, 71);
}

li:hover {}

.cn-button {
  width: 150px;
}

.banner {
  background-color: rgb(30, 0, 255);
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  transition: all 2s ease-in;
}

.about {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  transition: all 2s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="nav-bar">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="nav-bar-text">
        <p>Navbar Text And Logo</p>
      </div>
      <ul>
         <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Author</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Other Books</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Quotes</a></li>
        <li><a href=https://github.com/popados> [ Popados Github ] </a></li>
        <li><button class="cn-button" id="cn-button">+</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="banner">
    <h2>Book Title and Banner</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="about">
    <h2>About Author</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="other-books">
    <h2>Other Books</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, a `<div>` can't be a direct child of a `<ul>`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I changed the div - and to clarify I'm putting an img too.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/aFyPZzL

Answer (score -1):

there. this is a simple code that able to solve your issue. you may implement this code to yours by editing here and there. hope it help to solve your problem.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.zoom {
  float: left;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  transition: transform .3s;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.zoom1 {
  float: left;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: transform .4s;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid red;
}



.zoom:hover {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: scale(1.5); 
}

.zoom1:hover {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: scale(1.5); 
}
```

```html
<h1>Zoom on Hover</h1>
<p>Hover over the div element.</p>
  
<div class="zoom">
<h2> Menu</h2>
</div>
<div class="zoom1">
<h2> About Us</h2>
</div>
<div class="zoom">
<h2> Contact</h2>
</div>
<div class="zoom1">
<h2> Profile</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not the expected output I'm looking for. Refer to the images just posted.